# Formula to calculate sum of amount at 7% rate to 10th term.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm developing a Unity Game and I want to calculate below thing fast.

4, 4.28, 4.58, 4.90

Next number is 7% addition to the earlier number. 
4 * 7 / 100 + 4 = 4.28;

4.9 - 4.58 = .32;       4.58 - 4.28 = .30;    4.28 - 4 = .28;

Amount formula can me used to find number to nth term. Like below calculated to 3rd & 4th term.

A = P(1 + r)^t

4(1+0.07)^2 = 4.58;
4(1+0.07)^3 = 4.90;

I want a formula to calculate sum of compound interests to 10th term. The formula that'll calculate 7% of the earlier number and add it to next number till 10 times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the formula $$k\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$$ where $r = 1.07$ in this case and $k=4$.